# generate 100 color combination html

Tags: html, css, generator

i have an html template with 4 basic color Textheader, page basckgroung, navebar color,content backbround.
I want to generate different color styles so i can apply it dynamically and get different color scheme

i have tried css onine color chemers and the rest, but am looking of a service that will eneble me preview the color i choose by applying it to an html page online.

any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of integrated IDEs for browsers popping up - try Googling for "browser IDE" or "browser integrated development environment" or the like. Some of the more sophisticated ones will allow you to mark up and style a complete web page right in the browser with real-time visual feedback.

However, for this particular purpose, I'd recommend keeping it simple and using Firefox's [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension. Once installed, just navigate to the page you're developing, right-click the area of the page that you want to change and click "Inspect Element" in the context menu that appears. Firebug will list the CSS styles applied to the element in question and allow you to change them, and see those changes live.

Answer (score -1):

I believe firebug is for debugging as the name sounds,and i decided to do the stuff manually.